# sed multiline replacement with Apaches' mod_sed

Tags: apache, sed

I want to tweak the apache output for certain files, so that this:

```
<template>
  <p>... something in there ...</p>
  <template>... something in there ...</template>
  ... more stuff ...
</template>

<script>
  ... my script ...
  export default something;
</script>
```

becomes this:

```
const template = `
  <p>... something in there ...</p>
  <template>... something in there ...</template>
  ... more stuff ...
`

... my script ...
export default something;
```

(This converts a vue.js single file component into a ES6 native module)

I found that I could use `mod_sed` to achieve this and for the most part it works fine. I can replace the opening `<template>` and the closing `</script>` tags like this:

```
OutputSed "s/<template>/const template = `/g"
OutputSed "s/<\/script>/ /g"
```

But where I am having huge problems is when it comes to the middle part. So what I want is to **delete** anything from the **last** closing `</template>` tag (note that there might be nested `<template>` tags!) to the first (and only) `<script>` tag, including the tags themselves. Problem is that between those two tags there might be an arbitrary number of linebreaks and / or whitespace. So now I have multiline replacement which should be doable with `mode_sed` but all examples I found did not work in the apache context, I can't seem to get anything running so far.

Any help greatly appreciated!